# Why is syslogd not reporting messages to remote server during and just after the boot?

Tags: rsyslog

I configured `rsyslog` to send logs to a central logging server like this:

```
*.* @@192.168.1.20
$ActionExecOnlyWhenPreviousIsSuspended on
& @@192.168.1.21
& /var/log/failover
$ActionExecOnlyWhenPreviousIsSuspended off
```

It works well, except when machine is booting. When the virtual machine starts and approximately twenty seconds after the machine starts, no messages are sent to 192.168.1.20 or 192.168.1.21. However, `/var/log/failover` contains all those “lost” messages.

As a test, I started the machine and entered by hand:

```
$ logger 1
$ logger 2
$ logger 3
...
```

The first central logging server contains just:

```
Nov 28 13:57:40 demo arsene: 10
```

The second logging server contains no messages from the `demo` machine.

Finally, `var/log/failover` on `demo` machine contains:

```
Nov 28 13:57:10 demo rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="361" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Nov 28 13:57:10 demo rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104
Nov 28 13:57:10 demo rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
... # more than a hundred usual messages from the kernel
Nov 28 13:57:20 demo kernel: [   12.127981] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
Nov 28 13:57:21 demo arsene: 1
Nov 28 13:57:22 demo arsene: 2
Nov 28 13:57:23 demo arsene: 3
Nov 28 13:57:25 demo arsene: 4
Nov 28 13:57:27 demo arsene: 5
Nov 28 13:57:28 demo arsene: 6
Nov 28 13:57:30 demo arsene: 7
Nov 28 13:57:32 demo arsene: 8
Nov 28 13:57:37 demo arsene: 9
```

I encounter this issue for both Ubuntu and Debian virtual machines.

Additional notes:

1. The network connectivity looks fine. If I try `ping 192.168.1.20` and `curl google.com` during the period where the log messages are not sent to the log server, both `ping` and `curl` succeed.
2. Disabling the firewall of the logging server has no effect.
3. Running `tcpdump` shows that nothing is being sent to the log server during the twenty seconds period.
4. Other Ubuntu machines on the network (which were deployed using a very different approach) report their logs to the logging server fine, including during the boot.
5. By comparing the faulty machines to the correct ones, I noticed a version mismatch (7 vs. 8) for `rsyslogd`. Upgrading `rsyslogd` on faulty machines to version 8.14.0 haven't fixed the issue, but now I see the following message a bit *after* the log reporting starts working:

   ```
   Nov 29 02:18:39 demo rsyslogd-2359: action 'action 11' resumed (module 'builtin:omfwd') [v8.14.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
   ```
6. `diff` shows that `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` files are exactly the same between the new faulty machines and the old working ones.
7. A `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and even `apt-get dist-upgrade` haven't fixed the problem.

Comment: tcpdump showed there is icmp traffic to the logging server due to the ping but no udp traffic directed to the logging server, correct?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: `tcpdump` showed nothing at all during twenty seconds when running `logger` commands. Also, there should be normally no UDP traffic: the client is configured to use TCP (two `@` in `*.* @@192.168.1.20`). Note that `tcpdump` was called like this: `sudo tcpdump -n -s 1500 -X port 514`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that it was TCP. rsyslog has an [actionresumeinterval](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_actionresumeinterval.html) that is 30 seconds by default. Can you try setting it to a smaller value before any directives that use TCP connections? Depending on your network hardware and things like spanning tree settings, packets may be dropped for a few seconds after an ethernet port is brought up.

Comment: Excellent! By setting `$ActionResumeInterval` to `1`, the first message reported to the central log server during the boot is a kernel message at approximately 2.8 s. Can you please promote your comment to an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ThomasDickey said, networking may not be completely started when userland programs start to run. Many enterprise ethernet switches don't accept packets for [a number of seconds](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/10553-12.html) after an interface comes up, as they try to negotiate spanning tree settings.

rsyslog has an [actionresumeinterval](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_actionresumeinterval.html) setting that is 30 seconds by default. If you set it to a smaller value before any directives that use TCP connections, that will increase the retry rate, and the connections ought to get completed more quickly.

There are also [additional options](http://rsyslog-5-8-6-doc.neocities.org/rsyslog_conf_global.html) you can set to ensure that early messages which are  not sent immediately get delivered as soon as the connection is ready. For instance, you can use the options [similar to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18329443/240613):

```
$ActionResumeInterval 5
$ActionQueueType disk
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog
$ActionQueueFilename actionRq
$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1m
$ActionQueueSize 4000
$ActionQueueTimeoutEnqueue    0
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably networking hasn't completely started during those 20 seconds.  Until that happens, `rsyslog` has no one to talk to, so it is written locally.

Comment: It looks like the network is started. I tried to mix `logger <digit>` with `ping 192.168.1.20` and `curl google.com`: both `ping` and `curl` run successfully during those twenty seconds while logging messages are not reported to `192.168.1.20`.